# Encouraging the user to hit the NEED A RIDE button

Tags: user-expectation

We are building a carpool app, and I need to encourage the user to hit that `need a ride` button. For that I want to hint to them that there are rides closeby, so it will be useful to hit that `need a ride`.

**BEFORE**

[image: enter preformatted text here]

**AFTER**

Based on feedback, I have changed it to the below.
I request your review

- the location of the `available rides closeby`. This encourages the user to press the Call To Action button. I like what I have now.
- there was no space on the button, and could not make space
- should I zoom the toast into a small number on the `need a ride` button ? If yes, how do I make it look ok without taking up a entire row.

[image][image]

Comment: Mr downvoter, Whats wrong with this question ? do you know or dont have the words to express your opinion ?

Comment: What does "Will drive today" mean?

Comment: It means that this person will drive his own vehicle today. Once selected, "NEED A RIDE", will change to "OFFER A RIDE".

Comment: It seems better to have the user specify "I need" vs "I'll provide" first, then asking for the from/to info for whatever state they're in. That eliminates the confusing "will drive" checkbox. And if you make Now/Today less visually heavy, then your call to action becomes more clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your "Need a Ride" button needs to distinguish itself as a "[Call to Action](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/call-to-action-buttons-best-practices-guide/)".

A call to action button

- Needs to pop out from the page / application so it is noticed by the user. You can use colour, gradients, and 3d borders to make it pop. If you go with the toast notification, then the movement will also help draw the user's attention.
- Needs text that both represents the action, and gently urges them towards it. You could say "Get a Ride", or put a question mark at the end of "Need a Ride" (it should be a question). Displaying the number of available rides (in your screenshot 4) is also a nice touch for a call to action.
- Perhaps use a simple icon to indicate that this button / notification will take them somewhere else when clicked (to a list of options). An arrow is the simplest, but you could do something fancier like a zooming car icon.

EDIT:

Something like this might be good:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am having a hard time rewording "Will Drive Today". Also should I use the empty space next to `Go to` for showing the `number of rides around` ?

Comment: Are there any guidelines for showing "number of available car's" close to the call for action ?

Comment: @Siddharth I will edit my answer with my suggestion.

Comment: I like the suggestions. Unfortunately there is not enough space on the screen for a second line. I wonder if you can share some links of best practices here to choose from. thanks

Comment: @Siddharth I would say to make space for it. This extra info could be the extra push someone needs to click that button. :)

Comment: I'd avoid phrasing the call to action as a question (i.e. "Need a ride?") and instead use a positive verb phrase that describes the action, e.g. "Get a ride".

Comment: @MattObee Yes, good point!

Comment: I have tried to fit one more row, just could not. bigger devices needed a lot more of code to just fit it. And doing it consistently for 3000 android devices, I rather not have that extra row.

Comment: @Siddharth Perhaps you can do it in line with the other text (perhaps with a smaller font size)?

Answer (score 4):

You need some major changes in the flow of the app. I understand that you want to encourage people to share a ride with someone, if one is available.

First, you must know where I want to go. Only then you can suggest if there someone who can offer me a ride. Simply being nearby isn't enough (maybe they're going the other way).

So, I suggest this:

Screen 1:

[image]

Then state clearly with full text:

[image: mockup]

If you want to encourage them to share a ride, **fill the screen with intimidating relevant data.** Rephrase this with whatever you deem fits the communication theme of your app.

Comment: I think you mean *accompany* in that last screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused what the user is expected to do in this screen and what they would expect as a result. I'd need more context about the app screen shown but it seems that the app should be divided into sections. People who are looking for rides and people who are willing to drive. Ask that question at the front of the app and you effectively get people to where they need to be.

Comment: Well, this screen asks the user to define from to, what time and need/offer ride. But I need to encourage the user to hit that button, that can only happen when I share some information like (riders around you).

Comment: Thats the thing, I don't know what that button does as a user seeing this screen. Are those other people willing to drive me or people looking for a ride? The user first needs to state that he needs a ride or that he's willing to drive someone else. Then the form should change to support that answer. The button would then change to "4 People Need a Ride" or "Find me a driver" if I'm guessing correctly the form results.

Comment: thats the beauty, we dont need to decide that in advance, people talk, discuss and hten decide. when people look for carpool's they are not so fixed in their opinion on driving or being driven, they are open. all they want is to find people.

Comment: I don't agree at all. If I'm looking for a ride somewhere and don't have a vehicle, then what? I'm not offering a ride. Maybe I'm not understanding your idea though.

Comment: @Siddharth But that doesn't make sense. You can check the box saying 'Will drive today' but then press the button saying 'Need a ride'? So what, you can drive but need a ride?

Comment: When you press the "Will drive today", the button "need a ride" changes to "Offer A ride". Does this connect ?

Comment: I have updated the Question with the screen shots of both Offer and Need a ride.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is:

1. **Make your button blink  by changing color, for example blue and green alternately for short intervals** whenever you have updated available for rides close by.
2. Also you can put this information in the notification bar.

P.S. Be careful: Unnecessary or frequent blinking might annoy users. Use wisely.